Error at heroku at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
I'm making simple python app on heroku for testing.
It is not include any web services.
My app code:
import time
def index():
  while 5==5:
    time.sleep(40)
    print("Hello Heruko")

index()

My Procfile:
worker: python test.py

I also runned command in powershell:
heroku ps:scale worker=1

And I getting the errors:

at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/"
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"

Probably I need to add web to Procgfile. What should I add if I have no web service and no PORT.

You haven't defined a web process, and that's fine. Try scaling your web dynos down with heroku ps:scale web=0. Is your worker process running as expected? The error you quote isn't related to the command to scale up worker processes.

I tried ti run it and get "couldn't find that process type (web)". Yes, worker process running as expected.

"couldn't find that process type (web)" is also correct and expected if you're not running web dynos. Are you trying to visit your app in a browser? Maybe by running heroku open? Something is trying to request web content from it, based on the error message.

From the app page there is the button "Open App".  So I'm trying to open it and expect that I will see my print() results. But instead I see an error page.

Ah, you're misunderstanding that feature. Heroku is primarily designed to serve web applications, and heroku open / "Open App" opens a web browser that makes an HTTP request to your app. Since you aren't running web dynos, you shouldn't expect to see anything there. Instead, check your logs.
